# Wordpress shortcode: Refer to element in DOM

Tags: php, wordpress, dom, shortcode

I want to create a shortcode that searches the document for a certain element whose DOM-position is in a defined relation to the shortcode.

Example:

```html
<div>
  <div class="target" data-target="SomeValue">SomeValue<div>
  <div>more html here</div>
  <div>[gettarget]</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="target" data-target="SomeOtherValue">SomeOtherValue<div>
  <div>more html here</div>
  <div>[gettarget]</div>
</div>
```

How can the function `gettarget` access its sibling-div of class `target` (there will be exactly one) and fetch its content (or its `data-target`-attribute, doesn't matter). So finally I want

- the 1st call of `gettarget` to have access to `SomeValue` and
- the 2nd call of `gettarget` to have access to `SomeOtherValue`.

The furthest I could get was:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$doc->loadHTMLFile($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
var_dump($xpath);
```

which yields:

```
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.phpobject(DOMXPath)#11113 (1) { ["document"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" }
```

That's not my document :-/

Comment: `How can the function gettarget access its sibling-div of class target` It cant, in wordpress the page hasn't been completed when `do_shortcode` is called.  Further more only content within an open and close shortcode `[start]content[/start]` is passed to the shortcode, none of the outer content is accessable (without the use of javascript).

Comment: You could use a filter such as `add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_function_name' )` a regular Expression `/\[gettarget\]/`, and something that is not a short code `[gettarget]` as WP leaves them in if they are not actual shortcodes.  And then as you have the full content in your hands, you can access what you want in the DOM.  etc. etc..

Comment: What are you wanting to do with those values? Because you can enqueue a JS file that grabs them on document ready pretty easily.

Comment: @Second2None - thanks for adding that, that was what I meant by `(without the use of javascript)` in my first comment.  But you said it better ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments

> *-How can the function gettarget access its sibling-div of class target?-* It cant, in wordpress the page hasn't been completed when [your shortcode] is called. Further more only content within an open and close shortcode `[start]content[/start]` is passed to the shortcode, none of the outer content is accessable (without the use of javascript)
>
> You could use a filter such as `add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_function_name' )` a regular Expression `/\[gettarget\]/`, and something that is not a short code `[gettarget]` as WP leaves them in if they are not actual shortcodes. And then as you have the full content in your hands, you can access what you want in the DOM. etc. etc

And it seemed like as good an answer as any, so...

Something like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_function_name' );

function filter_function_name($content){
    //if no [gettarget] bail
    if(false === strpos($content,'[gettarget]')) return $content;


    $doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($content);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    var_dump($xpath);

    //for example remove [gettarget] our not shortcode, shortcode
    $content = preg_replace('/\[gettarget\]/', '', $content);

    return $content;
}
```

I've only ever used Dom Document one time, (then I learned about PHPQuery, and never looked at it again).  But this way your not double loading the page, I'm realy not sure what you get from this `$doc->loadHTMLFile($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])` from inside wordpress.  Maybe just a template file or such?

The way I have it above, I know that the `content` is what wordpress is going to put out on the page.  Not to mention I have no idea how you would make any output changes from the way you had it.  This way you can just modify the content and return it and it's changed.

-note- One last thing, it's been a minute but If I remember if you have something like a shortcode `[gettarget]` but you don't actually have a shortcode for it, it just remains in the content.  If that is correct, then what I said above should be pretty close. We can use this to our advantage and make it look like it's a shortcode inside the WP admin area, and in the output (by removing it).

I thought about doing it with JavaScript, but alas I am to lazy to put that much into it...

Anyway hope it helps.